# How to vocally change text between upper or lower case in windows 7dictation voice to text

Tags: windows-7, microsoft-word, voice-command

When using windows 7 dictation with Microsoft word,
Sometimes the dictation capitalizes certain words.
So, after dictating a paragraph or sentence, I want to select all of the and say a command the changes it all to lower case.

Sometimes I want to select a bunch of words and change it to all upper case, or just capitalize the first letter of each word.

What is the voice command for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For Window's Speech Recognition, from [Microsoft's website](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/common-speech-recognition-commands#1TC=windows-7):

- Capitalize the first letter of the word: `Caps word`
- Capitalize all the letters of the word: `All caps word`
- Make all the letters in the word lowercase: `No caps word`
- Change the next number of words to uppercase: `Change next X words to uppercase`
- Change the next number of words to lowercase: `Change next X words to lowercase`